# How to make star rating based on percentage shown in image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Im trying to create star rating based on score or percentage. I have created codepen for inline stars. But don't understand how to do for stars shown in image. Stars should not be inline, they should formed a triangle.
Will you please help me with that.

and my [codepen link](https://codepen.io/LeoZoe/pen/vejoaj)

```css
/*---------- general ----------*/
body {
    background: #ff7070;
    color: #F3FCF0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

/*---------- star rating ----------*/
%flex-display {
    display: flex;
}
.star-rating {
    @extend %flex-display;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.back-stars {
    @extend %flex-display;
    color: #bb5252;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #843a3a;
}
.front-stars {
    @extend %flex-display;
    color: #FFBC0B;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #d29b09;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f4e64b7c17.js"></script>
<div class="star-rating">
    <div class="back-stars">
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>>
        
        <div class="front-stars" style="width: 70%">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is my codepen link          https://codepen.io/LeoZoe/pen/vejoaj

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Don't provide external links to any images or videos

Comment: But I uploaded image I don't know why it is not showing, And I have provided link of my codepen. What else I can do?

Comment: Add your codepen to your question using the live snippet. That helps everyone that is willing to answer your question

Comment: @Leo, today you can't upload image for the stack overflow server ,because it's had some issue

Comment: I was trying to add link in question but it was giving me an error. I did indention in codepen but still no use'

Comment: @Leo sir, use snippet (Ctrl-M)

Comment: Done and thanks for teaching me that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing left:0 in .front-stars class

Sometime browsers render absolute element using left 0 some time not, So we should always mention combination of two at least( from left right top bottom)

Thanks